# Open an existing text file in WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program that enables a user to search text files in an open file dialog. The user is then able to open an existing text file they choose and edit it. However, my problem is that when they file opens it appears blank. What am I missing?

```
private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        TextBox openText = new TextBox();
        var OpenFile = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        Nullable<bool> Success = OpenFile.ShowDialog();
        OpenFile.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        OpenFile.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

        if (Success.HasValue && Success.Value)
        {

            openText.Text = OpenFile.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
           //cannot open file
        }


    }
```

Comment: Move the ShowDialog line AFTER the settings for DefaultExt and Filter. ShowDialog is a blocking call. It shows the dialog and doesn't return until your user presses OK or CANCEL

Comment: You are only using the `FileName` and not the content. Try `File.ReadAllText()` and see if that has something &mdash; also make sure that the file itself has something.

Comment: @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan I tried using File.ReadAllText() but i'm getting an error. ReadAllText is underlined in: openText.Text = File.ReadAllText(OpenFile.FileName);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
openText.Text = OpenFile.FileName;
```

with this:

```
openText.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(OpenFile.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use File.ReadAllText()

```
openText.Text = File.ReadAllText(OpenFile.FileName);
```